# Homebrew parity install fails with 'no available formula'

Tags: parity, installation, mac-osx, brew

The following installation of Parity via Homebrew on MacOS:

```
 brew install parity --beta --verbose
```

fails with

```
 Error: No available formula with the name "parity"
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ethcore recently moved everything from `ethcore` to `paritytech`. To fix this, untap ethcore:

```
brew untap ethcore/ethcore
```

and switch to paritytech:

```
brew tap paritytech/paritytech
```

and continue as usual:

```
brew install parity --beta --verbose
```

Comment: it changed to `brew install parity --devel`, see here: https://www.parity.io/ethereum/#download